# How to show indoor annotations on MKMapView

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

I need to show an indoor floor plan in a MKMapView. So far I have managed to load custom map tiles into MKMapView. But when I try to show annotations it does not show in correct location. The space between latitudes are not equal. I think it’s because MKMapView maps the globe into flat surface. But in my case I need to show annotations in a flat surface. Any idea how to do this?

EDIT : Anyone know how to convert geographic coordinates to cartesian coordinates? That will solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Apple just updated its demo project:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html

Take a look, there are information about how to translate geolocation (spherical) to flat location.